# Random Number generating in java without having any number of 0 in it

Tags: java, random

I have to generate 5 digit random number , without having any zeros in it. I have tried with below code, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Is there any better way to do this?

```
        public  Integer generateLastFiveSequenceNumbers()
        {
            Random ranndomNumber = new Random();
            Random replaceNumber = new Random();

            Integer fiveDigitRanndomNumber = 11111 + ranndomNumber.nextInt(99999);
            Integer replaceZeroNumber = 1 + replaceNumber.nextInt(9);


            String tempValidation = fiveDigitRanndomNumber.toString();
            char[] ch = tempValidation.toCharArray();

            for(int i = 0 ; i < ch.length-1 ;i++)
            {
                if(ch[i]=='0')
                {
                    ch[i] = '1'; 

                }
            }

            String newValue = new String(ch);
            Integer finalNumber = Integer.parseInt(newValue);
            return finalNumber;
        }
```

Comment: `i < ch.length-1`  --> `i < ch.length`. But you could also just pick 5 random numbers 0 < n <= 9 and assemble them into a 5 digit number.

Comment: The number you have won't be very random, since 1 is twice as likely to appear as any other digit. Consider generating 5 digits in the range 1-9 and concatenating them into a string.

Comment: I like the suggestion by @MadPhysicist ... another approach is to generate a random number with the nextInt method and then replacing the 0 digit with random non-zero digits

Comment: You're not using the replacement numbers, but I see the idea you had. It wasn't bad actually. You also don't need separate random number generator for this. One random stream will suffice.

Comment: replacement of zero with 1 was just an example in actual code I intended to replace it with random variable- replaceNumber by converting in Character value and then again to string and then int.

Comment: Apology for the error in the for loop. Actually was tring 2-3 method so forgot.

Comment: Thanks Jhonny and Mad Scientist for the correction and help. I will try to concatenate into string and then convert into integer as I need 5 digits only ( from 10000 to 99999 and not from 0-99999).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your intended method of replacing zero digits with additional random numbers is reasonably sound in theory, you are not using the replacement digits anywhere. Your final verification loops over all but the last index, which is the error that causes zeros to appear sometimes. Replacing all zeros with just ones defeats much of the randomness since ones are now twice as likely to appear as any other digit.

A simpler solution might be to concatenate five random digits that are guaranteed to be in the valid range to begin with. Since your return value is a number, you don't need to deal with strings at all:

```
public  Integer generateLastFiveSequenceNumbers()
{
    Random ranndomNumber = new Random();
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        result = result * 10 + (randomNumber.nextInt(9) + 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea above with an int stream:

```
    public static int generateLastFiveSequenceNumbers( ) {
        Random r = new Random();
        return r.ints(11111, 99999+1)
                .filter(i->!String.valueOf(i).contains("0"))
                .limit(1).findFirst().getAsInt(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Combination of the above answers:

```
Integer rand = Integer.valueOf(
  IntStream.rangeClosed(1,5)  // repeat 5 times.
      .map(x -> { return new Random().nextInt(9) + 1;}  // Random between 1 and 9.
      .boxed()                         // Convert to a stream of Integer objects.
      .map(String::valueOf)               // Convert from Integer to String.
      .collect(Collectors.joining()));       // Concat them all together.

System.out.println(rand);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void generateRandom(int howMany) {
    int c = 0;
    int multiplicator = 1;
    Integer number = 0;
    while (c < howMany) {
        number += multiplicator * getRandom();
        multiplicator = multiplicator * 10;
        c++;
    }
    System.out.println(number);
}
public static Integer getRandom() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt(9)+1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution uses a BiFunction (java 8 only).

```
BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Integer> customRandom = (min,max) -> {
    int val = 0;
    Random r = new Random();
    do {
        val = min + r.nextInt(max);
    } while (String.valueOf(val).contains("0")); // skip randoms containing '0'
    return val;
}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println(customRandom.apply(10000,99999));
```